# RSpec leaves record in test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Whenever I run a user test, RSpec leaves the Fabricated user in the test database after the test has completed, which is messing up my other tests.  I will do a `rake db:test:prepare`, but when I run my tests again, the record is recreated in my database. I have no idea why this is happening. It only happens with user objects.

In my spec_helper file I even have:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Here is an example test that creates a record:

```
it "creates a password reset token for the user" do
  alice = Fabricate(:user) 
  post :create, email: alice.email
  expect(assigns(alice.password_reset_token)).to_not eq(nil)
end
```

Fabricator:

```
Fabricator(:user) do
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  password 'password'
  name { Faker::Name.name }
end
```

Could this have anything to do with my users model?

Answer (score 25):

you should use a gem called database_cleaner that will truncate your database and reset everything automatically so in your gem file add the gem database_cleaner after that inside your spec_helper.rb configure it

spec_helper.rb

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

and then create a new file in your spec/support directory

spec/support/shared_db_connection.rb

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection=ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

Now whenever you run your tests the database will be reset.This was taken from the book 'Everyday Rails testing with RSpec' by Aaron Sumner

Answer (score 9):

Each test is wrapped in a database transaction. That means that everything created during the test should be gone when the test finishes. Therefore, I would suspect that whatever you have in your database was made outside the test itself (like in a `before(:all)` block).

Also this doesn't guarantee that your database will be empty each time you run your tests. It might be possible that you accidentally added a record somehow, and now it just keeps reverting to that state.

If you want to make sure your tests have a shiny database each time, you should have a look at  the [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem.

Comment: Very old post i know, but I'm currently having issues with data being deleted from my database (a legacy project i've picked up. To be clear are you saying that anything within, `before :all do ... end` is not transactional? Why would this be and I have been scratching my head over this for a day now, the documentation is very limited on this. for example, this code includes `before :all do
    User.delete_all
  end`. Edit: Ok just found, this (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions). wow, time to refactor a lot of code...in order to get my original task done grrr!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to make sure RSpec tests run in transactions (Rails does this by default)

`spec_helper.rb`

```
config.around(:each) do |example|
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    example.run
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, the line `post :create, email: alice.email` seems like a likely candidate for doing the actual user creation.

Stub that line out with an bogus test and see if you're still getting a user created in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

My problem turned out to be that I was was using `before(:all)` in my RSpec files which I found out the hard way that the data created does not get rolled back. I switched to `before(:example)` per this article: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions